# python imageIO() ffmpeg output 3D ndarray

Tags: python, ffmpeg, hevc, h.265, python-imageio

I'm trying to encode and than decode a collection of images using imageIO in python with the ffmpeg plugin and the HEVC codec.

The stream I'm using is an ndarray of shape (1024,512). When I use the writer.append_data() on each image, the shape is as above (1024,512). After writer.close() is called, I create another reader on the video just made from above. When interrogating a single image of the video it's shape is (1024,512,3). This is all grayscale, so I only expected an array of uint8's in the shape of (1024,512). Why did ImageIO add 2 more dimensions to my video? I only want one.